# Moment Generating Function Supremum

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm studying probability, and am having trouble with the following:

---

Let $X$ be a uniform R.V. on $[0,1]$. Compute the moment generating function $M(t)$ of $X$. Compute $I(y) = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}\{ty - \ln M(t)\}$.

---

Computing the moment generating function is easy enough; it's $M(t) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{t}(e^t-1) &t\neq 0 \\ 1 &t=0 \end{cases}.$

However, I don't see how to compute $I(y)$. 
I can see it is $$\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}\{ty - \ln M(t)\} = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}\{\ln \left( e^{ty}/ M(t) \right) \}.$$
For $y \geq 1$, this seems to approach infinity as $t \to \infty$. For $y < 0$, the value goes to infinity as $t \to -\infty$.

For $y \in [0,1)$, the value goes to $-\infty$ as $t \to \infty$ and as $t \to -\infty$.

The desired supremum is attained when the argument $te^{ty}/{(e^t-1)}$ achieves its maximum. Its derivative is zero when 
$$ M(t) = \frac{e^t-1}{t} = \frac{e^t}{yt+1}. $$

This doesn't seem to lead anywhere though. Is there some nifty probability trick to this? I think there must be a way to use the fact that $M$ is moment generating function, but I'm not seeing it...